# The strange ordering of Sharkovskii

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

### Introduction

In this challenge, we will be dealing with a certain ordering of the positive integers.
The ordering goes like this:

```
   3,    5,    7,    9,    11, ...
 2*3,  2*5,  2*7,  2*9,  2*11, ...
 4*3,  4*5,  4*7,  4*9,  4*11, ...
 8*3,  8*5,  8*7,  8*9,  8*11, ...
16*3, 16*5, 16*7, 16*9, 16*11, ...
 ...
... 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
```

We first list all odd integers greater than 1 in ascending order.
Then we list two times odd integers greater than 1, then 4 times, then 8 times, and so on: for all **k**, we list **2<sup>k</sup>** times the odd integers greater than 1 in ascending order.
Finally, we list the powers of two in *descending* order, ending at 1.
Every positive integer occurs in this "list" exactly once.

More explicitly, consider two distinct positive integers **A = n·2<sup>p</sup>** and **B = m·2<sup>q</sup>**, where **n, m ≥ 1** are odd, and **p, q ≥ 0**.
Then **A** comes before **B** in the ordering, if one of the following conditions holds:

- **n > 1**, **m > 1** and **p < q**
- **1 < n < m** and **p = q**
- **n > m = 1**
- **n = m = 1** and **p > q**

This ordering appears in the surprising mathematical result known as [Sharkovskii's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharkovskii's_theorem), which concerns the periodic points of dynamical systems.
I will not go into the details here.

### The task

Your task in this challenge is to compute the above ordering.
Your inputs are two positive integers **A** and **B**, which may be equal.
Your output is a truthy value if **A** comes before **B** in the ordering, and a falsy value otherwise.
If **A = B**, your output should be truthy.
You can take **A** and **B** in either order, as long as you're consistent.

You don't have to worry about integer overflow, but your algorithm should theoretically work for arbitrarily large inputs.

### Test cases

Truthy instances

```
3 11
9 6
48 112
49 112
158 158
36 24
14 28
144 32
32 32
32 8
3 1
1 1
```

Falsy instances

```
1 2
1 5
11 5
20 25
2 8
256 255
256 257
72 52
2176 1216
2176 2496
```

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>53</s> 49 bytes

```
f=(a,b)=>b<2||a>1&&(a&b&1?a<=b:a&1|~b&f(a/2,b/2))
```

Explanation:

- If b is 1, then a precedes (or equals) b
- Otherwise, if a is 1, then a does not precede b
- Otherwise, if both a and b are odd, then use regular inequality check
- Otherwise, if a is odd, then it precedes b
- Otherwise, if b is odd, then a does not precede b
- Otherwise, divide both a and b by 2 and try again.

Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Arnauld.

Comment: Nice. I didn't think about using recursion here. Would `a&1|~b&1&f(a/2,b/2)` work?

Comment: @Arnauld I'm not sure, I was worried that it would loop indefinitely.

Comment: It can't because `b<2` will eventually be true. Now, another problem is that you'll process more iterations than needed and get floating point values. But I can't find any counterexample that would not work as expected.

Comment: @Arnauld Ah, right, I wasn't using `b<2` originally, but I guess it will work now.

Comment: @Arnauld Better still, since `f(a/2,b/2)` only returns `0`, `1`, `false` or `true`, I don't even need the `&1`.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <strike>87</strike> 71 bytes

```python
k=lambda n:[n&~-n<1,(n&-n)*cmp(n&~-n,1),n/(n&-n)]
lambda a,b:k(a)<=k(b)
```

This probably won't win any size awards, but this answer works by constructing a 3-tuple using 3 expressions from an integer that when lexicographically ordered will result in the correct ordering.

In readable terms, the tuple is for **A = n·2<sup>p</sup>**:

```
[n == 0, p * (1 - 2*(n == 0)), n]
```

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 50 bytes

```python
lambda*l:cmp(*[([-n][n&n-1:],n&-n,n)for n in l])<1
```

Each number is mapped to a triple whose sorted order is the desired order.

- The primary value is  `[-n][n&n-1:]`, which handles the powers of 2 at the end. The bitwise "and" `n&n-1` is zero exactly when `n` is a power of `2`. If so, we get the list `[-n]`, and otherwise the empty list `[]`. This puts all powers of 2 at the end of the order, in decreasing order.
- The secondary value `n&-n` extracts the power-of-2 factor of `n`.
- The final value `n` tiebreaks equal powers of 2 in favor of the greater number.

The respective tuples are passed to `cmp` to see if that comparison is `<=0`. Python 3 would save a byte with float division `(n&n-1<1)/n` for the first value in the triple, but lacks `cmp`.

Comment: Isn't `cmp(...)<=0` equivalent to `cmp(...)<1`?

Comment: @mathmandan Yes :)

Comment: I think it's permissible to take the integers in reverse order and use `~` instead of `<1`

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>70</s> 64 bytes

Could probably be golfed some more, but as a first attempt:

```js
x=>y=>(a=x&-x,x/=a,b=y&-y,y/=b,y<2?x>1|b<=a:x>1&(b>a|b==a&y>=x))
```

Takes input with currying syntax `(x)(y)`. Returns `0` / `1`.

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

x=>y=>(a=x&-x,x/=a,b=y&-y,y/=b,y<2?x>1|b<=a:x>1&(b>a|b==a&y>=x))

console.log('Testing truthy instances ...');
console.log(f(3)(11));
console.log(f(9)(6));
console.log(f(48)(112));
console.log(f(49)(112));
console.log(f(158)(158));
console.log(f(36)(24));
console.log(f(14)(28));
console.log(f(144)(32));
console.log(f(32)(32));
console.log(f(32)(8));
console.log(f(3)(1));
console.log(f(1)(1));

console.log('Testing falsy instances ...');
console.log(f(1)(2));
console.log(f(1)(5));
console.log(f(11)(5));
console.log(f(20)(25));
console.log(f(2)(8));
console.log(f(256)(255));
console.log(f(256)(257));
console.log(f(72)(52));
console.log(f(2176)(1216));
console.log(f(2176)(2496));
```

Comment: You can take out the brackets around and inside `b>a||(b==a&&y>=x)`, won't make a difference to execution.

Comment: @XavCo7 It's OK to remove the brackets inside but not around. All existing test cases would still pass, but an input such as `[1, 5]` would be incorrectly identified as truthy.

Comment: @Arnauld I'll add that as a new test case for the future.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>89</s> 84 bytes

```
->\a,\b{my \u=*>max a,b;a==first a|b,flat [1,2,4...u].&{(3*$_,5*$_...u for $_),.reverse}}
```

```
{my \u=*>@_.max;@_[0]==first @_.any,flat [1,2,4...u].&{.map(*X*(3,5...u)),.reverse}}
```

([Try it online.](https://tio.run/#VHmyh))

Not exactly short, but I thought it would be interesting to write a solution that actually generates the ordering sequence (up to a safe upper bound for each sub-sequence), and then checks which input appears in it first.

For example:

- For input `2, 3` it generates:

  ```
  3 5
  6
  12
  4 2 1
  ```

  ...and then observes that `3` appears before `2`.
- For input `9, 6` it generates:

  ```
  3 5 7 9 11
  6 10
  12
  24
  48
  16 8 4 2 1
  ```

  ...and then observes that `9` appears before `6`.

It could be smarter and generate even less of the sequence, but that would take more bytes of code.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:b<2or[f(a/2,b/2),a>1,0,1<a<=b][a%2+b%2*2]
```

A recursive solution similar to Neil's.

Comment: This seems to mess up some test cases. It says `f(158,158)` is False and `f(2,8)` is True.

Comment: @xnor Oops, should be fixed now.

Comment: This says `f(1,5)` is False.

Comment: My bad, I meant that `f(1,5)` should be False, but the code gives True.

Comment: @xnor Ah, I spotted the bug, fixed now (for good I hope). I went about following Neil's description a bit too loosely.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 27 bytes

```apl
1⊃∘⍋⍮⍥{p⍵⍮⍨-⍵⍴⍨⍵=2*p←⊥⍨~⊤⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/w0fdTU/6pjxqLf7Ue@6R71Lqwse9W4FM1fogllbgCwgw9ZIqwCo4VHXUiC/7lHXEqBY7f80kFBvH8S4ruZD640ftU0E8oKDnIFkiIdn8H/1nNS0EoXMYoXUioLU5JLUFIWSotJUHYWizPQMsHhaYk5xqjqXhpGJQpqCiYGmgoaJAZBlZKIJFbMAiVnAxcCyJhYgdRYQHVwQFkIdUJZLV1cXqt/MBChuZgLVDxYH84yNgOLGRhAVYHEjiCIA)

A tacit dyadic function whose left argument is `a` and the right is `b`.

The approach is almost identical to [xnor's Python 2 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103993/78410), in that we convert each number to a nested array and do lexicographical comparison between them.

#### Part 1: Convert number to nested array

```apl
{p⍵⍮⍨-⍵⍴⍨⍵=2*p←⊥⍨~⊤⍵}  ⍝ Input: positive integer N
                  ⊤⍵   ⍝ Convert N to binary digits
                 ~     ⍝ Flip all the bits (1 to 0, 0 to 1)
             p←⊥⍨      ⍝ Count trailing ones and assign it to p
                       ⍝ (maximum power of 2 that divides N)
         ⍵=2*          ⍝ Test if N itself is equal to 2^p
     -⍵⍴⍨              ⍝ If true, create 1-element array containing -N;
                       ⍝ otherwise, an empty array
 p⍵⍮⍨                  ⍝ Form a 2-element nested array;
                       ⍝ 1st element is the above, 2nd is [p, N]
```

#### Part 2: Compare two nested arrays

```apl
1⊃∘⍋⍮⍥f  ⍝ Input: A (left) and B (right)
     ⍥f  ⍝ Evaluate f A and f B
    ⍮    ⍝ Create a 2-element nested array [f A, f B]
   ⍋     ⍝ Grade up; indexes of array elements to make it sorted
         ⍝ Here, the result is [0 1] if A ≤ B, [1 0] otherwise
1⊃∘      ⍝ Take the element at index 1 (0-based)
```

The dfn syntax does support conditional statements e.g. `{a:x ⋄ b:y ⋄ z}` meaning `if a then x else if b then y else z`, but it's way too verbose to use in this case.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 65 bytes

```
OrderedQ[{1,#}&/@#//.{a_,b_/;EvenQ@b}->{2a,b/2}/.{a_,1}->{∞,-a}]&
```

Unnamed function taking a list of positive integers and returning `True` if the list forms an ascending sequence in the Sharkovskii order, `False` otherwise. (In particular, the input list doesn't have to have only two elements—we get the added functionality for free.)

The heart of the algorithm is the function `{1,#}&/@#//.{a_,b_/;EvenQ@b}->{2a,b/2}`, which repeatedly moves factors of 2 around to convert an integer of the form `m*2^k`, with `m` odd, to the ordered pair `{2^k,m}` (and does so to every element of the input list). `OrderedQ` then decides whether the resulting list of ordered pairs is already sorted; by default, that means in increasing order by the first element, then increasing order by the second element.

That's exactly what we want, except numbers that are powers of 2 follow different rules. So before checking in with `OrderingQ`, we apply one last rule `/.{a_,1}->{∞,-a}`, which converts (for example) `{64,1}` to `{∞,-64}`; that puts powers of 2 in the correct spot in the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, <s>143</s> 138 bytes

Basically a relatively straightforward implementation of the criteria:

```
e n=head[k-1|k<-[0..],n`mod`(2^k)>0]   -- exponent of 2
f n=n`div`2^e n                        -- odd part
a#b|n<-f a,p<-e a,m<-f b,q<-e b=n>1&&(m>1&&p<q||n<m&&p==q||m<2)||n<2&&m<2&&p>q||a==b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FYtNCoMwEIXXeooBSzBgRIXSTcYTdNelWExQUSRjbG278e52snk/H@85MxMg@M/@2F93ggu8p/XHdk1u5wCE02D6ZlHlsWjVFHneZtS5te/S6rnIumjjkUfU9fM3oJQvUsYmsQdpNYLJvFYDmwvNZltoFqkuhUhdUK@3g7eOEyJHpysZQCWEC@JrhgbRQhxFAOf5Bw)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>159</s> <s>158</s> <s>153</s> <s>144</s> <s>142</s> 141 bytes

*Saved <s>a</s> 2 bytes thanks to Kritixi Lithos!*

This is mainly just to practice golfing my Python!
Used the formula given by the OP rather than the ways of all the cleverer  answers

```
f=lambda a,p=0:(a&1)*(a,p)or f(a>>1,p+1)
t=lambda(n,p),(m,q):(n==1)*(m==1)&(p>=q)or (m>1)&(p<=q)|(n<=m)&(p==q)or m==1
lambda a,b:t(f(a),f(b))
```

Comment: You can golf it by removing the unnecessary spaces: for example in `(a, b)` on the second line where you can remove the space between the comma and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
ΣxÓs1ǝzDg≠i(]Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OKKw5OLDY/PrXJJf9S5IFMjNvD//2hjHQVDw1gA) or [validate all test cases](https://tio.run/##LYs9CsJQEIT7PcWCjYWFO2/3/fTB3iMoiKSySCNCDmBtLQQ8gIdIYechvMhzjSnmmxmGOXW7fXuowGYxPpv6fpzHWyev@6U5fq5Du@z7bV3VwCJUOJJmTyAtk4l5tUwhMpREGdmpHEABM31lIZnkDzaSH7BmOH2G@dts9kQJbCBIiiyQ@E/QEr8).